# Manhwa in which the main character is a side character that made the male lead obsessed with her

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I am looking for a manhwa (Korean comic). The main character is created along side the male lead, for the original female lead when she was born. They both live in a institute like place for people who were created like they were but for different people. They are supposed to live there until the person they were created for chooses between the two of each of them, the other one is usually killed.

The main character became aware of this for some reason so she gets close to the person she was created with. He is rebellious and gets beaten often and is aggressive towards everyone but the main character, so she is often made to feed him.

There is a part of the story when they are  still in the institute where the head of the institute is interested in the main character and in having her as his own. However I don't know if he was still interested in her after she left.

When it came time for the original female lead to choose between the two of them she chose to take both of them home because she didn't want either of them to be killed. When they left the male lead was obsessed with the main character.

When they got out of the institute the original female lead gave them the option to be free. The male lead told the main character that he would follow her if she left.

The male lead had black hair.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Also, writing in sentences, with proper words, and using punctuation, will make people a lot more willing to help you.

Comment: No problem I try to do my best to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is ***[I Will Rewrite the Dead End Novel](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/i-will-rewrite-the-dead-end-novel)***.

> Yes, I possessed someone, but I can't remember at all who I was in my previous life. All I remember is just this guy's face before my eyes. We were together the day I opened my eyes for the first time as one of the many test subjects of the Magic Tower wizard's experiment. And strangely enough, this guy seems to know more about my previous life than I do. This is the world of a novel, a tragic novel with only pain and misery for every single character, where the only one I can trust and rely on for survival is myself, I have to run away from this guy who, in the future, will kill the female lead's entire family. He is a psychopath seeking the destruction of this world. And finally, I managed to escape his grasp and thought I could live a peaceful life.
>
> [image: Promotional image for "I Will Rewrite the Dead End Novel," depicting the characters, Yul and Kal.]

The protagonist, a young woman named Yul, is a minor character in the world of a novel set in a magic empire. She became aware that she was a character in a novel a few years earlier, and knows the plot of the novel, including future events, but has no memory of her previous life.

In this world, wizards normally live longer than ordinary humans, but there's a disease that can kill them instantly if their mana is depleted. As a solution, they come up with the idea of using magic to create people to serve as living mana stores for them. Each "black magic test subject" is created from the mana stone of a specific person, so they can later be paired with that person when that person reaches adulthood and registers with the wizard's association.

Yul was created from the mana stone of the Heroine of the novel, Estella Demetrice, as was Kal, a black-haired young man who's due to become the antagonist of the novel, according to the original plot. They've both spent their lives as prisoners within a magic tower run by a master and his subordinates. Kal regularly rebels against his captors and receives beatings as punishment. Yul is the only person who shows him kindness, using a medical kit to treat his wounds.

Estella eventually visits the tower and is asked to choose either Yul or Kal to be her pair. She asks what'll happen to the one she doesn't choose, and is told by the magic tower master that the one not chosen will no longer be of any use, since they can't be paired with anyone other than her. Estella says she's willing to pay five times what she originally agreed to pay if she can take both of them, and the magic tower master agrees.

Estella then leaves the tower with Yul and Kal in her carriage, and offers them the choice to either live in her mansion or go free if they prefer. Yul initially decides to go with Estella to her mansion but secretly plans to run away, if only she can find a way to ditch Kal, who follows her around like a lost puppy.

Comment: Yes thank you so much!